# Google Play Music API for Android

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm working on a music application for Android.
I need two things:

- Get album cover for artist, album name, track name, etc;
- Open Google Play page for buying this album.

For the first thing I'm currently using [iTunes API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) -- but this is not patriotic for true Android developer. If Google Play Music has similar service, I would preferred to use it. Does it exist?

What about second? I can use this code to show all search results according with my query:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                             .setData(Uri.parse("market://search?q=<My Query>"));
startActivity(intent);
```

But I want to show album or track buying page exactly. Is is possible for Google Play?

Comment: did you solve it? I have the same question. I saw an app Shazam can do that. but does't know how it does.

Answer (score 17):

There's no **official** API for this from Google.

However, you can use an *unofficial* API that is being developed by Simon Weber. It's called [Unofficial-Google-Music-API](https://github.com/simon-weber/Unofficial-Google-Music-API), and it seems to be actively maintained(as of this writing).

[The documentation](http://unofficial-google-music-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and examples are pretty straightforward, and you can find details about the song's metadata [as listed here](http://unofficial-google-music-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/metadata.html). Specifically, it gives an url to download cover art **and** the id for matching in the Play Store.

You may have to play around with the URL a bit for your search, though. For instance, you can use the returned `albumMatchedId` field to search by album like:

> https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bdkf6ywxmrhflvtasnayxlkgpcm

This should bring you to the album's page, where you can purchase each song or the entire album.

I haven't found a way to jump straight to a specific *track*, but I'm not sure if that's possible anyway, judging from the layout of the app.

Comment: Is it legal to use such unofficial api ?

Comment: Is there any official api available now for android app integration?