# How do I get access to a Google Play Music library on Android?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I'm trying to do a deep integration with Google Play Music. I need to be able to access the following from my Android app:

1. Library content directly uploaded by free users
2. Library content purchased but not downloaded by free users
3. Library content purchased and downloaded by free users
4. Podcasts subscribed but not downloaded by free users
5. Podcasts subscribed and downloaded by free users
6. Library content saved but not downloaded from GPM cloud by Artists,
   Albums, and Songs, from a paid account.
7. Library content saved and downloaded from GPM cloud by Artists,
   Albums, and Songs, from a paid account.

I'm aware of the [Unofficial API](https://github.com/simon-weber/gmusicapi) and I know I can get some local data from the ContentProvider. What other approaches are available?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Google Play Music is not yet included in the list of supported Google Play services API. References:

- [Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)
- [Google Play services APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/packages)

However, it is noted in [Accessing Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client) that

> If the Google API you want to use is not included in the Google Play services library, you can connect using the appropriate REST API, but you must obtain an OAuth 2.0 token. For more information, read [Authorizing with Google for REST APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth).

You may want to also regularly check [Google APIs for Android - Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) to know the latest updates on Google APIs for Android.

Suggested solution given in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755260/google-play-music-api-for-android) might also help.